# What areas of research use linear algebra the most?

Tags: education, linear-algebra, differential-equations

I'm in my 4th semester as a physics and recently added a minor in math. I'm in my second linear algebra course, and am finding it extremely interesting and fun to understand. To complete my minor, I need to take a methods course and want to take Numerical Linear Algebra. I would enjoy to do research in physics from a linear algebra standpoint, but I'm not sure what branches would benefit from this.

Should I go this route? Or would a course in Numerical Methods for Differential Equations, or even a Numerical Methods tailored toward scientists/engineers be more suitable?

Comment: Short answer - all branches of Physics benefits from advancements in linear algebra. Vector spaces and matrices and tensors are so common in many Physics fields, such as classical mechanics, relativity, quantum physics, and many more. This was just some tiny fraction of fields using linear algebra. Probably linear algebra can only compete by popularity in Physics only with calculus + differential equations. If you know these methods,- you can grasp 90% of physics books.

Comment: I'm only guessing at the content of the courses based on the titles. But, I would guess Numerical Linear Algebra would cover things like the singular value decomposition, efficient ways to do common matrix operations like computing a determinant or matrix inverse, etc -- these things are used more in statistics and data analysis than physics, per se. I think differential equations is probably more likely to be directly relevant for physics. But, also keep in mind that it's worth doing what you find interesting, and see where it leads.

Comment: I would also guess a generic "numeric methods for scientists and engineers" would be less in depth than a dedicated course in a specific topic like linear algebra or differential equations. But, what really matters is the content of the course and who is teaching it. Assuming you have one, I would talk to your academic advisor.

Comment: Calculus, in its modern incarnation, is 'heavy duty' linear algebra. Take for instance the tangent bundle, this is a *vector* bundle.